# is it possible to build desktop/web based ap using ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

is it possible to build desktop/web based ap using ionic framework . I have trying hard making my raw html to get used in ionic framework for using as a web . But structure is not getting correct . Lots of  js error . i am novice , please help and guide

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for testing purposes - that's what 'ionic serve' is for, but that will only work after you get some infrastructure in place (see http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/).

Ionic is intended for mobile apps, I would suggest you put a web-centric UI framework on top of your angular code if your want to go web - sth along the lines of Angular UI.

Comment: Actually i want to build both web and mobile ap , how  i m going to do that  using ionic framework . Can you guide me on this